# Can ps filters be combined with AND rather than OR logic

Tags: ps

Can the ps command be used on its own to filter down to a subset of results rather than creating a superset?

For example `ps -C <command>` gives me all `<command>` processes and `ps -u <user>` gives me all process belonging to `<user>`. But `ps -C <command> -u <user>` gives me all processes named `<command>` **or** all processes belonging to `<user>`, when what I'm really after is all processes named `<command>` **and** all processes belonging to `<user>`.

Obviously I can filter with grep, but I was wondering if what I'm after could be achieved with ps on its own.

I'm using `-C` and `-u` for the purposes of an example, but really I'd like a more general way of combining any of the ps filters with 'and' rather than 'or'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; this is documented in the [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#DESCRIPTION):

> Except as described below, process selection options are additive.
> The default selection is discarded, and then the selected processes
> are added to the set of processes to be displayed. A process will
> thus be shown if it meets any of the given selection criteria.

The exception:

```
--deselect
      Select all processes except those that fulfill the specified
      conditions (negates the selection).  Identical to -N
...
-N    Select all processes except those that fulfill the specified
      conditions (negates the selection).  Identical to --deselect.
```

(Of course, NOT (A OR B) = (NOT A) AND (NOT B), so you might be able to cook something up if you're more interested in negative matches, but this would be too unwieldy otherwise.)